# ASP.NET Core проблема с асинхронными запросами в базу данных

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

У меня возникла проблема с выполнением асинхронных запросов к базу данных при использовании Entity Framework. Когда я пытаюсь получить какое - либо значение из бд, например:

```
[Authorize]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id != null)
        {
            Worker worker = await _context.Workers.FirstOrDefaultAsync(w => w.ID == id);
            if (worker != null)
            {
                return View(worker);
            }
        }
        return NotFound();
    }
```

То появляется следующее исключение:

```
The provider for the source IQueryable doesn't implement IDbAsyncQueryProvider. Only providers that implement IDbAsyncQueryProvider can be used for Entity Framework asynchronous operations.
```

Вот класс контекста доступа для бд:

```
public class EnterChatContext : DbContext
{
    public EnterChatContext(DbContextOptions<EnterChatContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TopicMessage> TopicMessages { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Topic> Topics { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Note> Notes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<GroupChatMessage> GroupChatMessages { get; set; }
    public DbSet<File> Files { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Worker> Workers { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        foreach (var relationship in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes().SelectMany(e => e.GetForeignKeys()))
        {
            relationship.DeleteBehavior = DeleteBehavior.Restrict;
        }

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("User");
        modelBuilder.Entity<TopicMessage>().ToTable("TopicMessage");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Topic>().ToTable("Topic");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Note>().ToTable("Note");
        modelBuilder.Entity<GroupChatMessage>().ToTable("GroupChatMessage");
        modelBuilder.Entity<File>().ToTable("File");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Company>().ToTable("Company");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Worker>().ToTable("Worker");
    }
}
```

Вот класс модели Worker

```
public class Worker 
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Пожалуйста, введите имя работника!")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Пожалуйста, введите фамилию работника!")]
    public string SecondName { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }
    public string StringStatus
    {
        get
        {
            if (Status == true) return "Да";
            else return "Нет";
        }
    }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Пожалуйста, введите пригласительный код для работника!")]
    public int? InviteCode { get; set; }

    public Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

Я никак не могу найти могу найти информации по данному исключению. Я так понимаю проблема с классом контекста, нужно использовать что-то другое вместо DbSet<>...

Comment: А так `await _context.Workers.ToListAsync().FirstOrDefault(w => w.ID == id);` сработает? Хотя это плохое решение.

Comment: Какая БД используется?

Comment: В моём asp.net core 2 приложении я также использую DbSet и все хорошо, но у меня бд mysql

Comment: @tym32167 localdb

Comment: Тогда действительно странно. Обновте нугет пакеты, если есть что обновлять.

Comment: @tym32167 возможно проблема в нугет пакетах. есть обновление для Microsoft.AspnetCore.All. Только при обновлении происходит ошибка: Пакет "EntityFramework 6.2.0" был восстановлен с помощью ".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1", а не целевой платформы проекта ".NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0". Этот пакет может быть не полностью совместим с вашим проектом.

Comment: Так удалите `EntityFramework`  и поставьте  [`EntityFramework Core`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема заключалась в конфликте EntityFramework и EntityFrameworkCore. Асинхронные методы просто обращались не к той реализации, которой нужно. Я убрал EntityFramework из проекта и использовал директиву

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
```

Answer (score 0):

Точно ответить не могу, но везде рекомендуют установить NuGet пакет
[Ссылка на англоязычный форму с таким же вопросом](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit/issues/49)

Comment: установил, не помогло